# A man who sometimes works for the UN accidentally sells the Earth to an alien

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Sci fi story from the 1950s:  In New York, a man in a trenchcoat approaches and offers to buy planets.  The man selling eventually "sells the earth".  The buyer says write me a bill of sale and put "in my official capacity" on it.  After signing, the seller remembers that he sometimes sells surplus property for the UN.  He tries to buy the earth back.  The buyer admits he is an alien and needs to buy parts for his crashed spacecraft.  The seller takes all the money and buys the parts for the alien, who tears up the bill of sale.

Comment: "Bernie the Faust" by William Tenn.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely *Bernie the Faust*. It was asked before in [Aliens want to buy mineral & fishing rights for the moon & earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92921/aliens-want-to-buy-mineral-fishing-rights-for-the-moon-earth). It ends: "The only trouble is I’ll never know. All I know for sure is that I’m the only guy in history who sold the whole goddamn planet. And bought it back!"

Comment: Ted, if the question has been answered to your satisfaction, please "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft OP needs to confirm this is correct before we can close it.

Answer (score 22):

["Bernie the Faust"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41615), a 1963 novelette by [William Tenn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Tenn), which was also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92921/aliens-want-to-buy-mineral-fishing-rights-for-the-moon-earth). You might have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?41615). You can read a review at [Variety SF](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2009/05/william-tenn-bernie-faust-novelette.html).

**In New York, a man in a trenchcoat approaches and offers to buy planets.**

He doesn't start out buying planets. He starts small:

> So the office door opens. This little guy with a dirty face, wearing a very dirty, very wrinkled Palm Beach suit, he walks into my office, and he coughs a bit and he says: "Would you be interested in buying a twenty for a five?"

After that the guy buys the Golden Gate Bridge and the Sea of Azov. The first person narrator, Bernie, takes his money and gives him what amount to quitclaim deeds:

> "I know what I want. The Golden Gate Bridge in San Francisco. A hundred and a quarter. Take it or leave it."
>
> "I'll take it. If that's what you want, you're the doctor. But look—all I can sell you is my share of the Golden Gate Bridge, whatever equity in it I may happen to own."
>
> He nodded. "I want a receipt. Put that down on the receipt."

**The man selling eventually "sells the earth".**

> "Earth," he said, moving close to me so that I could smell his stinking breath. "I want to buy Earth. Lock, stock and barrel."
>
> "It's got to be a good price. I'll be selling out completely."
>
> "I'll make it a good price. But this is the deal I pay two thousand dollars, cash. I get Earth, the whole planet, and you have to throw in some stuff on the Moon. Fishing rights, mineral rights and rights to buried treasure. How about it?"

After some dickering they settle on $2700 for just the Earth.

**The buyer says write me a bill of sale and put "in my official capacity" on it.**

> I showed the receipt to Eksar. "This the way you want it?"
>
> He studied it, coughing. "Whatever equity you own or have a right to sell. All right. And put in, you know, in your capacity as sales agent, your professional capacity."

**After signing, the seller remembers that he sometimes sells surplus property for the UN.**

> Eksar must have known all along about the deal that Ricardo had thrown my way, getting rid of old, used-up office equipment for the United Nations here in New York. They'd given me what they called an authorizing document. In a file somewhere there was a piece of paper, United Nations stationery, saying that I was their authorized sales agent for surplus, secondhand euipment and installations.

**He tries to buy the earth back.**

Bernie buys the Earth back from Eksar, who ends up with a tidy profit:

> Six thousand, one hundred and fifty dollars.
>
> That was the price over and above what Eksar had given me. The final deal. Listen, it could have been worse.
>
> Even so, we almost broke up when we began talking payment.
>
> "Your bank's not far. We could get there before closing."
>
> "Why walk myself into a heart attack? My check's good as gold."
>
> "Who wants a piece of paper? I want cash. Cash is definite."
>
> Finally, I managed to talk him into a check. I wrote it out; he took it and gave me the receipts, all of them. Every last receipt I'd signed. Then he picked up his little satchel and marched away.

**The buyer admits he is an alien and needs to buy parts for his crashed spacecraft.**

Eksar admits nothing; money for spaceship parts is the theory Bernie's friends come up with:

> "Ricardo's got it, Bernie. Put yourself in this guy Eksar's position. He racks up his spaceship on a dirty little planet which it's against the law to be near in the first place. He can make some half-assed repairs with merchandise that's available here—but he has to buy the stuff. Any noise, any uproar, and he'll be grabbed for a Federal rap in outer space. Say you're Eksar, what do you do?"

Comment: Yes, Bernie the Faust is right! You may close my question. (My view of this page has no check mark and no Accept button.) --Ted.

Comment: Mod note: the acceptance comment above by "Ted K" appears to be from the same user who asked the question.

Comment: @TedK it seems you may have created 2 accounts. If you [go here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) you can get a mod to merge them for you. It'll work better for you in the long run, plus, when you log back in under the `Ted` account, you'll see the check mark to accept this answer, as only _you_ can do so.